# More than 100 GB disappeared on MacBook Pro 250GB SSD

Tags: applications, macos

I was installing a software on the MacBook Pro of my girlfriend when I have found that in " > About this Mac > Storage", it says that she have 134 GB of space used by "Applications"...

I have then looked at what she installed, and I see that the only apps she installed are Caffeine, Kindle, VLC, Google Chrome and Skype (along with the default applications of OS X).

I've downloaded [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to see what's happening, and it says that the Applications are taking up about 9GB.

The question then is... Where are all these gigabytes gone?

PS: Using the "Disk Utility" app, it says that 130 GB are used by Applications, but it also says that there are 202 GB of free space... I wonder how this can be possible since the SSD is just 250 GB...

Comment: Where do you find the "Informations about this Mac > Archive"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Apple > About this Mac > Storage"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe, the Spotlight is not indexing correctly any more.

Open the System Preferences > Spotlight/Privacy and drag the Macintosh HD icon to the window. Click OK. Choose the icon and and click the - sign to remove it, so that the reindexing routine starts. Test when completed.

Comment: I've already tried it, I'm not sure how to know when the procedure is finished tho...

Comment: The procedure might take some time, depending on the volume of your system. If you use any "antivirus" scanner just remove it. Furthermore run the terminal command diskutil verifyvolume / to see if there are any errors in the disk.

Comment: Ah, it's fixed now! I guess it's thanks to the re-index procedure then.

Comment: How do you do this on Catalina? I can go into Privacy and ADD (+) Macintosh HD icon. Then I can (-) manually. Mind you, when I opened the tab, it had no locations preventing Spotlight from searching.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) application (a free trial is also available).

This app help you to find out how you are using the space available and so you can identify what is occupying a large amount of space in your HD.

Comment: It has the same purpose of Disk Inventory X (which is free), I have already found that nothing is taking up all that space... I just wonder why OS X thinks so...

Answer (score -1):

Download an application called OmniDiskSweeper to see how the storage is being used. That should give a breakdown of all the files and locations.

Comment: I've already said that I've used Disk Inventory X, I don't see how suggesting an app that does the exact same task can help.

Answer (score -2):

/usr/local/mysql-8.0.11-macos10.13-x86_64 is been written by a virus delete it. I used daisyDisk to figure it out